# What version of MySQL is supported by Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

What version of MySQL will be provided as part of Amazon RDS SQL.
Would it be possible to control the updates, if we didn't want to upgrade to a certain patch version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment Amazon RDS supports only MySQL 5.1 and MySQL 5.5

> As of today, Amazon RDS supports the MySQL major versions MySQL 5.1
>   and MySQL 5.5. We plan to support additional MySQL major versions in
>   the future.

You have the possibility to choice minor version of these: like 5.1.3 or others.

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#78